# Appium page object model @AndroidBy is taking variable name instead of actual value

Tags: appium

I am using @AndroidBy in page object class

```
@AndroidBy(accessibility = "Animation")
public WebElement animationButton;
```

When I run the test I get the following error.

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.id: animationButton;

Whats interesting here is that appium is looking with wrong locator strategy(id instead of accessibility) with variable name as value not the actual value given.
Same happens when I used xpath or other locator strategies.

but works fine if use driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Animation").click();

I am unable to understand why this error is thrown.

Works fine when I use @FindBy with xpath but I cannot use accessibility id with it.

Comment: Any solution found? I'm also facing this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `@AndroidFindBy` instead of `@AndroidBy`

```
@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "Animation")
public WebElement animationButton;
```